# Python eve - set collation for resources

Tags: mongodb, eve

From MongoDB 3.4 on, it is possible to set a [collation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/#collation-document-fields) for the collections. Is it possible to tell eve to create my collections setting their collation?

The problem is that this has to be done at creation time:

(https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/#createcollection-collation-example)

> For a collection, you can only specify the collation during the collection creation. Once set, you cannot modify the collection’s default collation.

I know I can set collation in an index creation but then I need to specifically set the same collation when filtering data to make use of it, so eve queries wouldn't take advantage of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, if you specify a collation at creation time, it will be picked up and used by default, with no need to specify it at query/index creation time. Eve itself does not issue a `createCollection` command, it simply relies on MongoDB capability to lazily create it on the first write, if missing. So, if you can create your collection (with desired collation) beforehand, you should be fine and it will be used by Mongo on subsequent queries.